# bootstrap dropdown-toggle not working in mvc when we render a part of page with react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC app which has .cshtml pages as views and part of it has knockoutjs. I have a react sub folder to render few pages using react.

I have a page whose Index.cshtml has below snippet,

```
@section Css{
   @await Component.InvokeAsync("RenderLegacyScripts", new { module = "case-index", type = "css" })
}



@section Scripts
{
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("RenderReactAssets", new { type = "js" })
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("RenderLegacyScripts", new { module = "case-detail", type =     
  "js" 
  })
}

<partial name="Partials/_JobTemplate" />
```

with the line RenderReactAssets I am loading the react build folder.

If I load RenderReactAssets js scripts then dropdown-toggle not working.